# Asp.net core with Aurelia not showing api route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, aurelia

I'm just getting started with [Asp.net core api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api) and [Aurelia](http://aurelia.io/)

normally I work with [Laravel](https://laravel.com/).

I've installed everything + the aurelia router. Now I would like to make an api call to my asp.net core api but I don't see the json result?

The example controller looks like this:

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

}
```

But when I make a get request with google chrome `http://localhost:9001/api/values` I just see a blank white page? How should I contact my `api`?

**edit**

Startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Forum
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();
            app.UseDefaultFiles(); 
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the HTTP response status for your request made with google chrome?

Comment: Share your Startup.cs class please

Comment: I don't see a status code. @S.Petrosov please see my edit.

Comment: @Jamie press F12 in any Browser Developer Tools Window will be opened Go to Network and find your request there will be the response code for example like this http://take.ms/CtlcH

Comment: @S.Petrosov thanks I see this: https://s9.postimg.org/l1stfedhr/Schermafbeelding_1396-02-11_om_11.11.02.png

Comment: @Jamie have you seen my answer below :)

Comment: Yes thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But when I make a get request with google chrome http://localhost:9001/api/values I just see a blank white page? How should I contact my api?

You don"t see anything because of this line in your `Configure` defined into your `Startup` class.

```
app.UseMvc();
```

This line just enable attribute rrouting and doesn't add any default route for you.

You have two options :

**First Option:**

Use attribute routing by decroating your controller with this attrbute `[Route("api/values"]`.

**Second option:**

Use the `UseMvc` overload that make you define a route following your convention. So, in your `Configure` method juste  replace `app.UseMvc()` with this code:

```
app.UseMvc(routes => routes.MapRoute("default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
```

To learn more about routing follow this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing).

Answer (score 0):

Add some function like the below:

```
private void ConfigureRoutes(IRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
{
    routeBuilder.MapRoute("Default", "api/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
}
```

And change line

```
app.UseMvc();
```

To

```
app.UseMvc(ConfigureRoutes);
```

Now you will be able to send request to "api/Values/Get" url.